# Unable to change height of navbar with bootstrap.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I past over an afternoon to search an answer at my issue. I'm still blocked with that. I'm unable to change the height of the navbar in my *`/dist/css/bootstrap.css`* file.
I found a lot of topics who deals about this problem but any of them allow me to pass through my problem.

I have the feeling that any modifications I've done in my `bootstrap.css` do nothing. But when I tried to remain the script who include bootstrap in my `index.php` this does a major effect, so I know that bootstrap is successfully loaded.
Then I tried to modify some lines in `bootstrap.css` in order to test what does effect :

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:4px !important; 
    padding-bottom:0 !important;
    height: 28px;
}
.navbar {min-height:28px !important;}
```

I changed the height value.

The div class I use in my html code :

```html
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Medieval Fields</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
```

What I load in my head :

```html
<link href="../bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do not change the bootstrap core css. Add your custom styles in your stylesheet and link that after the bootstrap ones. This way your custom styles will overwrite those of bootstrap.

Comment: Have you checked if it is loading the minified version of bootstrap instead of the one you're editing?

Comment: @jackJoe  I added in the main post what i've loaded.

Comment: In that case that's the reason. `bootstrap.min.css` is not `bootstrap.css`!

Comment: Wow ok... my bad. The code seems to be modified itself now.

Answer (score 0):

**C**SS.

Use the C. The **Cascading** portion of the acronym refers to the fact that linking another style-sheet after bootstrap will overwrite the bootstrap values.

As Abhitalks pointed out. Sorry just saw that.

Comment: Yep, I already created 2 .css files where I put new codes outside bootstrap. But as jackjoe said, i loaded the wrong bootstrap :/